I am deploying a project made in SpringTool Suite using AWS
this is what I have in my configuration, I created a RDS in AWS because before I was using local MySQL
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://carinsurance.cheqj6hez0p4.us-east-             2.rds.amazonaws.com:3307/carinsurance");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("admin");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin123");
        return dataSource;
        
    }

and in PUTTY I am getting:
2024-04-06T13:42:31.674Z  WARN 26618 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

It looks like server address is not correct. The JDBC URL should be     jdbc:mysql://<AWS_RDS_INSTANCE_ENDPOINT>:3306/<DATABASE_NAME>
